# Calling Stored Procedures using ServiceStack with MySql

Tags: c#, ormlite-servicestack

I have a store procedure on a MySql database that does not return anything.  I simply does an update to a record.

I have tried doing things like

```
                var s = db.SqlScalar<string>("call SP_OrderSetPrintedStatus @v, @id", 
                                              new { v = 55, id = "AP2B7FUD" });
```

but it does not seem to work.  I also looked at the documentation to attempt to do this without the SP following

> Even the Table name can be a string so you perform the same update without requiring the Person model at all:
>
> db.Update(table: "Person", set: "FirstName = {0}".Params("JJ"), 
>             where: "LastName = {0}".Params("Hendrix"));

but the table: parameter and the Params do not seem to be defined so I wonder if I am referencing an incorrect assembly.  I am using ormlite 4.0.45.0

Answer (score 1):

For Executing SQL that doesn't return anything you can use [OrmLite's ExecuteSql APIs](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite#custom-insert-and-updates), e.g:

```
db.ExecuteSql("call SP_OrderSetPrintedStatus(@v, @id)",
    new { v = 55, id = "AP2B7FUD" });
```

Comment: Thank you!  Would you comment on the Update method where you say in your doc ...(table: ...Params?  I don't see that method available?

Comment: @Jeff it was renamed to UpdateFmt, [here's an example](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite/blob/master/tests/ServiceStack.OrmLite.Tests/ApiSqlServerTests.cs#L330). I've updated the OrmLite docs to match.

Comment: Also - I just tried..db.ExecuteSql("call SP_OrderSetPrintedStatus @v, @id", new { v = cpu, id = record });   Where cpu = 2 and record = "3E724TD7" and get syntax error to use near '2, '3E724TD7'' at line 1

Comment: @Jeff I just copied the SQL from your question verbatim, try adding braces around the args as I've never seen it used without in MySql. If you still get an error please post the full exception message.

Comment: I am sorry - but I am not sure of what you mean by adding brackets.  Which args?  An exception of type 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException' occurred in MySql.Data.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '[2], ['3E724TD7']' at line 1

Comment: Also with                 db.UpdateFmt( table: "orders", set: "QueuedForPrint = {0}".Params(2), where: "invoice_number = {0}".Params("AP2B7FUD"));
  Params is not found as an extension.

Comment: @Jeff braces around the args so it looks like a function call as seen in my answer. The [example I linked to](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite/blob/master/tests/ServiceStack.OrmLite.Tests/ApiSqlServerTests.cs#L330) shows Params was renamed to SqlFmt.